# Update statement to reorder a table queue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

There is a table with the following test data

```
PKId         EqId    Worker     Queue
1             1      Worker1      1
3             1      Worker3      3
2             1      Worker2      4
4             1      Worker4      7
```

Need to update the table which will rotate the Workers such that after the update statement the data will look as below

```
PKId         EqId   Worker  Queue
1             1     Worker1   7
3             1     Worker3   1
2             1     Worker2   3
4             1     Worker4   4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE @q TABLE (
  PKId INT, 
  EqID INT, 
  Worker VARCHAR(50), 
  [Queue] INT
) 

INSERT @q 
SELECT 1,1,'Worker1', 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1,'Worker3', 3 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,1,'Worker2', 4 UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,1,'Worker4', 7 

;WITH t AS (
SELECT
  PKId,
  [Queue],
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Queue]) AS rn
FROM @q 
)
UPDATE q 
SET [Queue] = q2.NewQueue
FROM @q q 
JOIN ( 
  SELECT
    t1.PKId,
    COALESCE(t2.[Queue], 
      (SELECT TOP 1 [Queue] FROM t ORDER BY [Queue] DESC)) AS NewQueue
  FROM t t1
  LEFT JOIN t t2
  ON t1.rn = t2.rn + 1
) q2 
  ON q.PKId = q2.PKId
```

Answer (score 2):

You can almost do this with a join:

```
select pkid, eqid, worker, queue, tprev.queue as newqueue
from t left outer join
     t tprev
     on t.pkid = tprev.pkid + 1
```

However, you end up with NULL for PkID = 1.  So, we need to add this in:

```
select pkid, eqid, worker, queue, coalesce(tprev.queue, lastone.queue) as newqueue
from t left outer join
     t tprev
     on t.pkid = tprev.pkid + 1 cross join
     (select top 1 queue from t order by pkid desc) as lastone
```

If you actually want to update, then we can put this in an update statement:

```
update t
    set queue = newqueue
    from (select pkid, eqid, worker, queue,
                 coalesce(tprev.queue, lastone.queue) as newqueue
          from t left outer join
               t tprev
               on t.pkid = tprev.pkid + 1 cross join
               (select top 1 queue from t order by pkid desc) as lastone
         ) newt
    where t.pkid = newt.pkid
```

I realize that your primary keys may have holes.  In this case, start with the following query:

```
select t.*, newQueue
from (select t.*,
             (select top 1 queue from t t2 where t2.pkid < t.pkid order by t2.pkid desc
             ) as newQueue
      from t
     ) t
```

In the update statement:

```
update t
    set queue = newqueue
    from (select pkid, eqid, worker, queue,
                 coalesce(Newqueue, lastone.queue) as newqueue
          from (select t.*,
                       (select top 1 queue from t t2 where t2.pkid < t.pkid order by t2.pkid desc
                       ) as newQueue
                from t
               ) t cross join
               (select top 1 queue from t order by pkid desc) as lastone
        ) newt
    where t.pkid = newt.pkid
```

Comment: Thanks - almost there I would think -- the only thing is that the PKid is not sequential. Also, I'm not sure how to use the last query in the update statement.

Comment: That may have been because I totally mangled the syntax.  I had two competing ideas; I think I've fixed it.

Comment: Tx - I'm naming the table 'temp' and using your query above I tried this but did not work  `update temp set queue = newqueue from (select PrimaryId, EquipId, worker, t.queue, coalesce(Newqueue, lastone.queue) as newqueue from (select temp.*, (select top 1 queue from temp t2 where t2.primaryid < temp.primaryid order by t2.primaryid desc ) as newQueue from temp ) t cross join (select top 1 queue from temp order by primaryid desc) as lastone ) newt where temp.primaryid = newt.primaryid` Also I will need to run this update after repeatedly so in that case the Order by Pkid will not work I guess